# Float type Data is not updating in MongoDB field of type double (Pymongo)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm working on a web app where I get the data through JQuery ajax (in String format) and convert it into Float type. And then want to update field in MongoDB which is of type "Double" already in database but the data is not updating.

```
update = {
    '$set': {
        'marks': marks
    }
}
exam = self.studentDB[ExamId]
exam.update_one({'qnNo': QnNo}, update)
```

But this code works if I parse the data into Integer type by using

```
int(marks)
```

But not with

```
float(marks)
```

Comment: there is no need for you to convert data into `float` before the `$set` process. MongoDB will handle the data conversion part on its own.

Comment: @hhharsha36 but I'm getting the number as string from frontend and when I tried to enter it without parsing it was saved as string in database.

Comment: It works perfectly fine in my local:  `s = "1.42"
update = {
    '$set': {
        'marks': float(s)
    }
}
c.update_one({}, update)`  . Try updating your pymongo

Comment: @hhharsha36 Sure, Thank you so much for helping. I hope it will work for me.